# Sql Server Resource Governor - track IO

Tags: sql-server, performance

I know I can use the performance counters to track Resource Governor CPU and Memory Usage.  Is it possibly to track the I/O usage for each work load group?  I haven't seen anything specific or any recommended practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource Governor does not manage I/O, it is just system resources for CPU and Memory.  Therefore, I don't believe there would be any way to get I/O per workload group.

Quote from [BOL on Resource Governor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx):

> Resource Governor enables you to specify limits on the amount of CPU and memory that incoming application requests can use.

Comment: Correct there's no way to have Resource Governor manage IO.

Comment: I didn't think so, but thought I'd throw it out to the experts, hoping I missed something.  Thanks.